# Eclipse Oxygen doesn't show any preferences

Tags: eclipse

Out of blue Eclipse Oxygen doesn't show any preferences. It was working OK, I've started it today (no updates, no new plugins etc) and now there are no ANY preferences? Windows 10 64b, Eclipse Oxygen 64b. Tried to restart it several times, can't change theme as well. Any help for this?

UPDATE: When I switch to another workspace then it works OK.

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in Eclipse's logs?

Comment: There are some project related errors but nothing related to eclipse itself as far as I can see.

Comment: Did you try to start Eclipse with the command line argument `-clean`?

Comment: @howlger tried, doesn't help

Comment: What if you switch to a new workspace with the (new) option _Copy Settings: Preferences_? And what with _Copy Settings: Workbench Layout_?